# Convert this string to a proper date

Tags: php

Is it possible to convert this kind of string:

```
00:12:57 Nov 05, 2014 PST
```

To a proper date?

im using carbon for mysql timestamps, and i get this kind of format when i receive response from paypal api.

My initial thought was to explode it, and reformat it and then do the converting, but maybe there is another proper way to doing it?

without exploding it and doing such stuff, am i able to transform such format to a valid one so i can use it to store in mysql (timestamp)

Comment: Have you tried the DateTime class?? http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert it to timestamp and then use [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format it like you want :

```
$timestamp = strtotime('00:12:57 Nov 05, 2014 PST');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);

// 2014-11-05 03:12:57
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this function will be useful to you :) :

https://www.php.net/strtotime

Answer (score 0):

`$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("read doc",$string_var);` should help...([doc](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat.php))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class for this. For example:

```
$date = new DateTime('00:12:57 Nov 05, 2014 PST');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```